# I have a UIPickerView/UIDatePicker which is initially scrolling unexpectedly

Tags: ios, swift3, uipickerview

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwOGf.png)
I have a UIPickerView/UIDatePicker which is initially scrolling unexpectedly and produced following in debug area..

**<_UIFeedbackRetargetBehavior: 0x60000011b750: prepared=0> is being deactivated more times that it'd been activated, this will raise soon!**

Does anybody have an idea?